# Cannot add data to table in MS Access 2013 from Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, ms-access, visual-studio-2012

I made a web form in Visual Studio 2012 and am making a User Management form so a manager can login and go to this page and edit, delete, or add users.  I'm using MS Access 2013 and I'm used to working in VS 2008. This exact same code works in VS 2008 with Access 2013. On the form I have a Gridview which is bound to the table in Access. For some reason the `if()` statement in the button `Click` event that calls the function in my data layer class keeps returning `false` so my result label keeps saying the user has not been added to the database.

I've tried passing the values as just `txtUser.Text` and how it's written now as `ToString()`.

Here's the button click code:

```
protected void btnAddUser_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


    //makes call to saveusers class to add the new user to the database sending the values with it
    if (clsDataLayer.SaveUsers(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/TPSDB.accdb"),
                                 txtUser.Text.ToString(),
   txtPassword.Text.ToString()))
        {
            //if saveusers function is successful and true then informs the user of the results

                grdEditManagers.DataBind();
                lblResults.Text = "The user has been added to the database!";

        }
        //if saveusers function is not successful or false then informs user
        else
        {
            lblResults.Text = "The user has not been added to the database!";

        }
}
```

Here's the `SaveUsers()` code in the `clsDataLayer` class:

```
//this function saves the new user
public static bool SaveUsers(string Database, string UserName, string UserPassword)
{

    bool recordSaved;
    // Creates transaction for rollback in case of error
    OleDbTransaction myTransaction = null;
    try
    {
        // creates variable of a new connection to DB
        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection("PROVIDER=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" +
                                                   "Data Source=" + Database);
        conn.Open();//opens connection
        OleDbCommand command = conn.CreateCommand();
        string strSQL;

        // beginning of the commit or rollback transaction
        myTransaction = conn.BeginTransaction();
        command.Transaction = myTransaction;

        //strSQL assigned to first and last names only
        strSQL = "Insert into tblManagerLogin " +
                 "(UserName, Password) values ('" +
                 UserName + "', '" + UserPassword + "')";
        // SQL command for stored procedure
        command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        command.CommandText = strSQL;


        // statement against connection returns number of rows affected
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();


        // ends the rollback or commit block
        myTransaction.Commit();

        // close database connection
        conn.Close();
        recordSaved = true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // rolls back both entries in case an error is caught
        myTransaction.Rollback();
        recordSaved = false;

    }

    return recordSaved;
}
```

Comment: well as you swallow the exception, you can't tell why recordSaved isn't set to true.  I'd also run strSQL directly in Access to check that works.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit puzzled as to why that code supposedly worked in Visual Studio 2008, because `PASSWORD` is a [reserved word](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/248738) in ACE/Jet so I would expect

```
INSERT INTO tblManagerLogin (UserName, Password) ...
```

to fail in any case. You'll want to change `Password` to `[Password]`, so while you're at it you can change your code to use a *parameterized query* like this

```
    strSQL = "INSERT INTO tblManagerLogin " +
             "(UserName, [Password]) VALUES (?, ?)";
    // SQL command for stored procedure
    command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    command.CommandText = strSQL;

    // add parameters to OleDbCommand
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", UserName);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", UserPassword);

    // statement against connection returns number of rows affected
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Yes it worked.  It was because like you said Password is a reserved word.  I wasn't really thinking about that. Once I put [] brackets around Password it worked. I can always change the table name too. Also I realize the reason it worked in 2008 was because the table field wasn't named Password. Thanks so much. Also for my next function I'm going to be doing adding parameters like your sample here.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

i have the same problem using studio 2012 and access 2013. I get the same result using C# and VB. It seem like studio reads the initial table values and then will not read the updated access file if additional rows are added. This is very easy to duplicate. Very frustrating!!!